# psqlDroid & postgreSQL 8.4.1 & Android & full-eng & make psql failed

Tags: android, postgresql, build, makefile, android.mk

I want to make an android platform with psqlDroid (for emulator).  [I followed these instructions:](http://code.google.com/p/psqldroid/wiki/BuildFromSource)

1. Download & configure the Android source tree
2. Download postgresql-8.4.1
3. Download the psqldroid patch
4. Extract the postgres archive and move the directory to `external/postgresql` under the Android source tree
5. Change into the `external/postgresql` directory
6. Apply the psqldroid patch
7. Run `sh create-symbolic-links.sh`
8. Change to the root of the android source tree
9. `make psql`

and result is the following:

```
build/core/base_rules.mk:78: *** Module name: psql

build/core/base_rules.mk:79: *** Makefile location: external/postgresql

....

build/core/base_rules.mk:90: *   Add "LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional" in the

....

build/core/base_rules.mk:102: *** user tag detected on new module - user tags are only supported on 
legacy modules.  Stop.

mike@ubuntu:~/myandroid$
```

so I opened and checked out `Android.mk` file in the path, `external/postgresql/src/interfaces/psql/`.

I could not find defined `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS`.

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this problem?

**Please help me. I'm ready to listen carefully any advice.**

If I miss anything, please let me know. I will attach it whatever.

Have a very fantastic day!

Comment: *Download postgresql-8.4.1*. Um, what?!? Why on earth would you download an old point release of an end-of-life PostgreSQL version? At the very minimum if you need 8.4 for some reason you should be using 8.4.22 (yes, that's 21 point-releases of updates later).

Comment: Actually I don't know why I choose, I just follow psqlDroid wiki page. Thank you very much, I will change right now.

Comment: I changed the code of Android.mk's inside of postgresql directory. That is to say, I just inserted "LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng" into the files. And now the error is changed -> No rules to make target 'psql'.  Stop. Please anybody help me :(

Comment: What are you even trying to accomplish here? Do you want to run the PostgreSQL server executable on Android?

Comment: Yes. that's what I want to do. and when I searched the How, I found psqlDroid...but it doesn't work for me..

Comment: Sounds like a pretty bad idea in the first place, IMO. PostgreSQL doesn't make a very good embedded database, and you're likely better off using something like SQLite.

Comment: The reason I'v been trying to import the postresql into the android is that we already have postgresql DB Server on the windows version application and we should develop the android version of the application. (PSQL DB servers share data easily with other PSQL servers.). If we change the database to SQLite, it may take longer time. Anyway...thank you so much for reply. 'make psql' is stil not working... Does anyone know how to import postgreSQL server into Android Jelly Bean 4.3?

Comment: See also follow-up post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27008993/398670 . Android isn't officially supported as a platform by PostgreSQL, so you might need to know a bit more about C programming and build systems to get it running. I really *don't* recommend starting with an obsolete version like 8.4.1, that's digging yourself a legacy hole before you even release your first product. Perhaps if you want Android platform support you should invest in a proper port and some buildfarm members (http://buildfarm.postgresql.org/) to auto-test it?